# Is the Canon radio wireless flash system the same in every country?

Tags: canon, wireless-flash

Is the Canon radio wireless flash system the same in every country?  I'm looking to use several Canon "RT" flashes, some bought in the UK and others bought in the US.  Will this work, or will there be compatibility issues?

Canon's system seems to be based on the same 2.4 GHz frequency no matter where the item is sold, so I'm assuming the system is universal worldwide.  However, I'd like this confirmed by someone that has first-hand knowledge.  I ask, as I know some wireless radio systems — notably, PocketWizards — use different frequencies depending on the locality due to local regulations.